# Examples of functions in $C(\mathbb{S}^1) \setminus H^{1/2}(\mathbb{S}^1) $

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $B$ be the open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I was wondering about (possibly simple) examples of functions which are

1. in $C^2(B)\cap C^0(\bar B)$ but not in $H^{1/2}(\partial B)$;

and (possibly simple) examples of functions which are

2. in $C^0(\partial B)$ but not in $H^{1/2}(\partial B)$;

I know about the counterexample of Hadamard, but I was wondering about simpler examples (as I don't need the function to be harmonic in $B$).

Comment: For the second question, apply Fourier theory to see that this can be done by finding a sequence $a\in \ell^1(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $(k a_k^2)_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}\not \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$. Once you have such a sequence, it defines continuous function $f(e^{i\theta})=\sum_{k} a_k e^{i k \theta}$ which then extends to some harmonic function. Now, finding such a sequence is decently easy. For instance, pick a positive sequence $b_k\to 0$ such that $kb_k^2\not \to 0$ and define $a_k$ to be $b_k$ if $k$ is the first $k$ such that $a_k<2^{-n}$ for some $n$ and $0$ else.

Comment: Oops... obviously it should have been $a_k=b_k$ if $k$ is the first $k$ such that $b_k<2^{-n}$ for some $n$ and $0$ else.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou this is very close to Hadamard construction. The reason why I want to find other examples is to have a better feeling of which kind of boundary data is lost through the variational approach.